# Is there a way to modify these column definitions programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a page that displays a list of items.

My markup is basically

```
<Grid x:Name="ItemGrid">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" x:Name="Column1Header"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" x:Name="Column2Header"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" x:Name="Column3Header"/>
...
<ItemsControl Name="ItemsList">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid x:Name="Items">
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" x:Name="Column1"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" x:Name="Column2"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" x:Name="Column3"/>
...
```

Two separate grids using star sizing (which means I can't use SharedSizeGroups.
Now I have to add a configuration option to hide `Column3` and the header. I can hide the header easy enough by setting the width to 0 in code, but 
I cannot figure out how to hide `Column3`. Looping through the items always results in null.

```
foreach (var item in ItemsList.Items)
{
  var container = ItemsList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as FrameworkElement;
  // container is null
}
```

Basically the two columns need to be the same size. The Grid is populated every 30 seconds with a new list of items if it matters but the grid sizing doesn't change once it's been loaded.

I also tried having both columns share a Style that defines the width, and then tried changing the style through code, but that didn't work out either.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ColumnDefinition}" x:Key="Column3Width">
   <Setter Property="Width" Value="15*"/>
</Style>
```

Modifying it resulted in the error: "After a 'SetterBase' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified."

Comment: Tried to bind the column widths to the header column's width?

Comment: @H.B., how could I do that? The only way I know of is either the SharedSizeGroup which isn't possible with star sizing, or sharing a style, which just results in the error mentioned above.

Comment: Something like `Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=ColumnXHeader}"`?

Comment: @H.B., That works perfectly. Thanks a lot, I'm still not that familiar with WPF, had no idea it was so simple. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad that worked. Might want to take a look at the [data binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) if you're new to this, it's a key mechanism in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the width of the items columns to the header columns:

```xml
Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=ColumnXHeader}"
```